# This App is not Authorised while using Firebase Phone Verification in Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, ssh, firebase-authentication

Hello I am getting this error while verifying phone number using Firebase phone Verification

```
This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct 
package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console.
```

I am working on support project which is live on Google play Store. I generated my debug **SSH1** from terminal and added that in firebase. I have only viewing rights in Firebase console and no access to Google playstore.
I have used Firebase phone authentication earlier in different Android as well as flutter projects too. I am sure my SSH-1 is correct. I guess I need to add my SSH-1 to Google playstore. If Yes then please explain me why I need to add SSH1 to playstore if I am running application in debug mode and if not then how can I get rid of this error?

Please answer this question with some explanation so that everyone will get correct understanding of this.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You do not need to add anything to google play.
- You must be using a physical device.
- Make sure that you have the latest `google-services.json` ready, configured and downloaded from firebase. Double check that you added it to your project in the folder path `/android/app`.
- You need to make sure that you enabled PHONE AUTHENTICATION here in FireBase console => Authentication => Sign-in Methods. [image]
- You already mentioned that you added your SHA-1 key, but I would double check again. If you however are using a signed APK [i.e built an APK that wasn't for debugging or didn't have the debug key], you will need to add that key to Firebase also.
- If you however had it working previously but then it stopped, it could be because the number was rate limited\throttled by firebase, so after enabling sign in with phone, be sure to add a test phone number so you don't get blocked for a certain time period.

Do those things and report back, I couldn't pretty much think of anything else.

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed check points given by you. But please add one more check point to verify google-services.json file. Actually it was not updated and I could not guess it could be wrong as this project was not created by me. Once again thanks for giving time for these detailed explanation.

Comment: @AfzalKhan absolutely. I assumed your google-services.json was configured properly, because if it didn't find it,it would be a different error as soon as the app builds, saying specifically `make sure you added and configured google-services.json`. I'll update the answer and make this point #1. Good day to you!

Comment: I am running signed apk and getting same error. I also added release SHA-1 to firebase console by getting from ```keytool -list -v -keystore "your jks file path " -alias "key name"``` and its still not working. Same error returns again.